# JSON Data formatting should be done in which layer in Spring MVC framework

Tags: json, spring-mvc

In MVC framework which layer is suppose to format/covert data to JSON. Should it be done in Web layer or in Service layer? In my opinion it should be done in Web layer (Spring Controllers) but some peole suggest to do that in Service layer. What are other people think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right.

I also think that JSON manipulation should be done on Web layer, doing this will make your code more manageable.

Comment: Yes I do not understand why Service layer should be dealing with constructing data in JSON form and passing it to Web controller.
I want to know what is the best design approach
1. Service gets the data from database, massage/convert it to JSON and send to Web Controllers? or
2. Service sends the raw data to Web controllers and web controllers convert the raw data to JSON and pass it to UI layer

Comment: It depends on the need and architecture of the application.

Comment: Do you have an idea on what cases it should be one in service layer?